# ASP.NET Web API Avoid saving file as “BodyPart_...”

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am trying to create an API that accepts keys and files uploaded through formData.

Before saving file physically I need to check if file type is accepted (is PDF, word...), if it is not accepted then file should be rejected and not saved in any folder.

I found a way how to do it and it is working successfully, but the problem is when file is rejected, I found that folder contains files which names start with BodyPart_...; I realized that they are saved only when file is rejected, is there a way to avoid that?

Below is my code:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
            {
                try
                {
                    // checking if multipart 
                    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
                    }

                    // checking contentType allowed
                    List<String> lstTypesAllowed = new List<String>();               
                    lstTypesAllowed.Add("application/pdf"); // pdf
                    lstTypesAllowed.Add("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"); // docx

                    // creating root
                    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploadfiles");
                    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

                    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                    // I guess this one is creating BodyPart_ file

                    // getting keys
                    var model = result.FormData["requestDetails"];
                    if (model == null)
                    {
                        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                        response.ReasonPhrase = "requestDetails cannot be null!";
                        return response;                    
                    }

                    // converting json to list of requestDetail 
                    List<RequestDetail> lstRequestDetails = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RequestDetail>>(model);

                    // checking if files exist 
                    if (provider.FileData.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // looping over each file
                        foreach (MultipartFileData fileData in provider.FileData)
                        {
                            string fileName = "";                           

                            // getting mediaType
                            string mediaType = fileData.Headers.ContentType.ToString();

                            // checking if mediaType is allowed
                            if (lstTypesAllowed.Contains(mediaType))
                            {
                                // here I rename then save file in folder Uploadfiles; I save request details of this file in my database
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                        response.ReasonPhrase = "No files uploaded!";
                        return response;
                    }            
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    response.ReasonPhrase = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                    return response;
                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
```

Comment: If you just want to be sure that the file gets deleted when rejected, why don't you call [File.Delete(string) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @n0idea thanks for your reply. I could delete it but is it a professional way? why it is anyway created? I was wondering if the solution could be another way of developing maybe... Couldn't Microsoft thought about checking contentType if allowed before creating file?